when using call function in web3.py im getting error
Error: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
import streamlit as st
from web3 import Web3
import hashlib
import json

# Connect to local Ethereum node (Ganache)
ganache_url = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"  # Adjust if needed
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))

# Check if connection is successful
if not web3.is_connected():
    st.error("Failed to connect to the Ethereum node.")
    st.stop()

# Set the default account (first account in Ganache)
web3.eth.default_account = web3.eth.accounts[0]

# Load ABI from abi.json
def load_abi(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as abi_file:
        return json.load(abi_file)

# Load ABI and Contract Address (Replace with your actual contract address)
contract_abi = load_abi('abi.json')
contract_address = "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4"  # Replace with your contract address

# Create a contract object
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)

# Streamlit UI
st.title("Deepfake Detection - Blockchain Integration")
st.write("Latest block number:", web3.eth.block_number)

def to_bytes32(hexstr):
    """ Convert a hex string to a bytes32 format. """
    return Web3.to_bytes(hexstr=hexstr)

def hash_file(file):
    """ Compute the SHA-256 hash of a file. """
    file_bytes = file.read()
    return hashlib.sha256(file_bytes).hexdigest()

# Upload video file
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a video file", type=["mp4", "avi", "mov"])

if uploaded_file:
    video_hash = hash_file(uploaded_file)
    st.write(f"Video Hash: {video_hash}")

    option = st.selectbox("Choose an action", ["Check Hash", "Store Result", "Retrieve Result"])

    if option == "Check Hash":
        if st.button("Check"):
            if video_hash:
                try:
                    is_present = contract.functions.isVideoDetected(to_bytes32(video_hash)).call()
                    if is_present:
                        st.success("The hash is detected as a deepfake.")
                    else:
                        st.warning("The hash is not detected as a deepfake.")
                except Exception as e:
                    st.error(f"Error: {str(e)}")
            else:
                st.error("Please enter a valid video hash.")

    elif option == "Store Result":
        result = st.number_input("Deepfake detection result (0 = Not Detected, >0 = Detected)", min_value=0)
        if st.button("Store"):
            if video_hash:
                try:
                    tx_hash = contract.functions.updateVideoResult(to_bytes32(video_hash), result).transact({'from': web3.eth.default_account})
                    web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
                    st.success("Result stored successfully on the blockchain.")
                except Exception as e:
                    st.error(f"Error: {str(e)}")
            else:
                st.error("Please enter a valid video hash.")

    elif option == "Retrieve Result":
        if st.button("Retrieve"):
            if video_hash:
                try:
                    result = contract.functions.getVideoResult(to_bytes32(video_hash)).call()
                    st.success(f"Deepfake Detection Result: {result}")
                except Exception as e:
                    st.error(f"Error: {str(e)}")
            else:
                st.error("Please enter a valid video hash.")
else:
    st.info("Please upload a video file to proceed.")


solidity code is as:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract DeepfakeDetection {

    // State variable with underscore prefix for clarity
    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) private _videoHashToResult; // Mapping to store results by video hash

    // Event for logging results
    event VideoResultUpdated(bytes32 indexed videoHash, uint256 result);

    // Function to get video result
    function getVideoResult(bytes32 videoHash) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _videoHashToResult[videoHash];
    }

    // Function to update video result with gas optimization
    function updateVideoResult(bytes32 videoHash, uint256 newResult) public {
        // Cache the state variable in memory to reduce SLOAD costs
        uint256 cachedResult = _videoHashToResult[videoHash];

        // Check if the new result is different to avoid unnecessary storage writes
        if (cachedResult != newResult) {
            _videoHashToResult[videoHash] = newResult;

            // Emit an event to log the update
            emit VideoResultUpdated(videoHash, newResult);
        }
    }

    // Function to check video detection status and return deepfakeness level
    function isVideoDetected(bytes32 videoHash) public view returns (bool isDetected, uint256 result) {
        // Get the result from the mapping
        uint256 detectionResult = _videoHashToResult[videoHash];

        // Check if the video is present
        if (detectionResult > 0) {
            // Video is present, return detected status and result
            return (true, detectionResult);
        } else {
            // Video is not present, return not detected status and zero result
            return (false, 0);
        }
    }
}


web3.py part for easy debugging:
from web3 import Web3
import json

# Step 1: Connect to local Ethereum node (Ganache)
ganache_url = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))

# Step 2: Verify the connection
if not web3.is_connected():
    print("Failed to connect to the Ethereum node.")
    exit()
else:
    print("Connected to Ethereum node successfully.")

# Step 3: Set the default account (first account in Ganache)
web3.eth.default_account = web3.eth.accounts[0]

# Step 4: Load ABI from a file
def load_abi(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as abi_file:
        return json.load(abi_file)

# Load the contract's ABI and address
contract_abi = load_abi('abi.json')
contract_address = "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4"  # Replace with your contract address

# Step 5: Create a contract object
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)

# Helper Function: Convert hex string to bytes32
def to_bytes32(hexstr):
    if len(hexstr) != 64:
        raise ValueError("Hex string must be exactly 64 characters long for bytes32.")
    return Web3.to_bytes(hexstr=hexstr)

# Step 6: Define a hardcoded video hash (64-character hex string)
hardcoded_video_hash = "0x" + "a" * 64  # Replace with actual hash if needed
video_bytes32 = to_bytes32(hardcoded_video_hash[2:])

# Step 7: Test "Check Hash" functionality
try:
    is_detected, result = contract.functions.isVideoDetected(video_bytes32).call()
    print(f"Check Hash Function - is_detected: {is_detected}, result: {result}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during 'Check Hash' function call: {str(e)}")

# Step 8: Test "Store Result" functionality
try:
    hardcoded_result = 1  # Assume 1 indicates detected as deepfake
    tx_hash = contract.functions.updateVideoResult(video_bytes32, hardcoded_result).transact({'from': web3.eth.default_account})
    receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    print(f"Store Result Function - Transaction hash: {tx_hash.hex()}")
    print(f"Transaction receipt: {receipt}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during 'Store Result' function call: {str(e)}")

# Step 9: Test "Retrieve Result" functionality
try:
    result = contract.functions.getVideoResult(video_bytes32).call()
    print(f"Retrieve Result Function - result: {result}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during 'Retrieve Result' function call: {str(e)}")


from web3 import Web3

# Connect to local Ethereum node (Ganache)
ganache_url = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))

# Ensure connection to Ethereum node is successful
if not web3.is_connected():
    print("Failed to connect to the Ethereum node.")
    exit()

# Contract ABI and address
contract_abi = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"videoHash","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"isVideoDetected","outputs":[{"name":"detected","type":"bool"},{"name":"result","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]'
contract_address = "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4"  # Replace with your contract address

# Create contract object
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)

# Hardcoded video hash (64-character hex string, 32 bytes without "0x")
video_hash = "a" * 64
video_bytes32 = Web3.to_bytes(hexstr=video_hash)

# Call the smart contract function with the hardcoded hash
try:
    is_detected, result = contract.functions.isVideoDetected(video_bytes32).call()
    print(f"Is Detected: {is_detected}, Result: {result}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during contract function call: {str(e)}")
'''


Make sure that your getVideoResult() is defined as a view function in your contract.

yes it is already defined as view function

Okay, instead of sharing the full script, can you please create the minimum reproducible version only having the call to the contract function with some hardcoded params, so that it'll be easy to debug?

i tried using transact function instead of call function for view type functions but i wasnt getting the return value instead i was getting some bytedata, can i extract anything from that?

Ideally, the view function should be called using .call instead of .transact. If you can just share the minimal script with some hardcoded params calling the function, I’ll try to figure it out.

i already uploaded the smart contract as well as just web3.py part , what do you mean by hardcoded params?

Your script is having some dependencies and a lot of lines of code that are irrelevant for testing that specific functionality of calling smart contract function. That’s why, I’m asking you to share the minimum reproducible version of the script, not the whole script.

added some code without anyother dependency than web3.py

It's working fine on my end, printing Is Detected: False, Result: 0. Is your local ganache node running?

yes its running fine , i can see the block number on my local ganache and the block number im printing on my frontend same , also as im using is_connected() , it should be connected right?

can you please tell me step by step what you did

I've deployed the contract on Avalanche Fuji testnet, and interacting with it. Here's the gist containing the script, it's the same as the one you've provided, just using the Avalanche Fuji public RPC url and my deployed contract address.

using Avalanche Fuji  could solve my problem? I have commented on your github

Checked and responded.
